# how to use variable for property in indexOf inside map function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function as below:

```
getValue(param) {
    var result = [];
    result = this.state.ObjectsData.map(x => {
        if (result.indexOf(x.param) === -1) {
            result.push(x.param)
        }
    });
}

//ObjectsData is array of objects

ObjectsData = [
    {tag: 23, name: vicky, gender: m},
    {tag: 13, name: sam, gender: m},
    {tag: 23, name: raj, gender: m}
]

//x can be any object like below:
x = {tag: 23, name: vicky, gender: m}
```

param is the propertyName like tag

I am getting param as undefined at the below line even though the param has some value before map and after map at line
`if (result.indexOf(x.param) === -1) { }`

I am trying to find unique values for any property like:
for tag: 23, 13. And yes, x.tag or x.name or x.gender works fine but I want to make propertyName dynamic

Comment: Are you trying to use indexOf to determine if the object already exists on results list?

Comment: you getting x.param as undefined is it ?

Comment: `x.param` is `undefined`. `x.tag` or `x.name` or `x.gender` should work though.

Comment: I am trying to find unique values for any property like: for tag: 23, 13. And yes, x.tag or x.name or x.gender works fine but I want to make propertyName dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to dynamically check the key whose name is the value of `param`, so instead of

```
if (result.indexOf(x.param) === -1) {
    result.push(x.param)
}
```

Which checks for the key named `param`, you want

```
if (result.indexOf(x[param]) === -1) {
    result.push(x[param])
}
```

Which checks for key with the name of the value of `param`

Comment: This worked. Great. It seems I was accessing the value of a property in a wrong way. Thanks a lot @FuzzyTree

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectsData = [
    {tag: 23, name: 'vicky', gender: 'm'},
    {tag: 13, name: 'sam', gender: 'm'},
    {tag: 30, name: 'raj', gender: 'm'}
]
result = _.map(ObjectsData,'tag'); //[23, 13, 30], use indexof result!
if(result.indexOf(23)===-1)
    result = 'not found';
else 
    result = 'found';
```

Comment: This would not give what I want. I am trying to find unique values for any property like: for tag: 23, 13. And yes, x.tag or x.name or x.gender works fine but I want to make propertyName dynamic